# How to update mysql tables between computers

Tags: mysql, database-design, synchronize

I'm working on a group project where we all have a mysql database working on a local machine. The table mainly has filenames and stats used for image processing. We all will run some processing, which updates the database locally with results.

I want to know what the best way is to update everyone else's database, once someone has changed theirs.

My idea is to perform a `mysqldump` after each processing run, and let that file be tracked by git (which we use religiously). I've written a bunch of python utils for the database, and it would be simple enough to read this dump into the database when we detect that the db is behind. I don't really want to do this though, less it clog up our git repo with unnecessary 10-50Mb files with every commit.

Does anyone know a better way to do this?

*I'll also note that we are Aerospace students. I have some DB experience, but it only comes out of need. We're busy and I'm not looking to become an IT networking guru. Just want to keep it hands off for them since they are DB noobs and get the glazed over look of fear whenever I tell them to do anything with the database. I made it hands off for them thus far.

Comment: Are you concerned with schema changes only or schema and data changes?

Comment: Why not just run a single server, with multiple remote users?

Comment: I would recommend having the database in a central location and having the data on the three local machines written directly to it.

Comment: Schema and data changes. I would like to have a single server with multiple users. Its just something I've never done. We're all students and I'm just doing this as I go. The big problem is that we're all working on traveling laptops, rarely on the same network.Centralizing the server is just something I've never had any experience with. If you think its the best answer, put it as an answer please and I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider following the Rails-style database migration concept, whereby as you are developing you provide roll-forward and roll-back SQL statements that work as patches, allowing you to roll your database to any particular revision state that is required.

Of course, this is typically meant for dealing with schema changes only (i.e. you don't worry about revisioning data that might be dynamically populated into tables.).  For configuration tables or similar tables that are basically static in content, you can certainly add migrations as well.

A Google search for "rails migrations for python" turned up a number of results, including the following tool:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-db-migrate

Comment: Ooh I like that idea. I'll look into it, and check this answer soon if there are no better.

Comment: I'll verify this because its the easiest way for DB 'version control'. I loved using the Rails utilities, and didn't know Python had such a thing. The only problem is that all the migrate files will still have to be synchronized with git, and I don't want the large files to clog our repo every time a change needs to be updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a DEV MySQL server on any shared hosting. (No DB experience is required).
Allow remote access to this server. (again, no experience is required, everything could be done through Control Panel)
And you and your group of developers will have access to the database at any time from any place and from any device. (As long as you have internet connection)